# Можно ли на Яндекс Картах работать с библиотекой Leaflet?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, карты, leafletjs

В частности интересует возможность использования плагинов Leaflet на карте Yandex. Что то типа такого: [Пример](https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/)

Answer (score 1):

В API Яндекса есть такой модуль - [модуль для региональной инфографики](https://yandex.ru/blog/mapsapi/modul-dlya-regionalnoy-infografiki-ot-shkoly-razrabotki-interfeysov?from=SO). Можете использовать его.

А так главная сложность в условиях использования API Яндекса - нельзя показывать подложку карты без копирайтов и средствами сторонних API. Но был плагин, который вроде без нарушений ПС вызывает карту Яндекса внутри leaflet - [вот он](https://github.com/shramov/leaflet-plugins)

Comment: "В API Яндекса есть такой модуль - модуль для региональной инфографики." Прикольно. Спасибо.

Comment: А посмотрите мой следующий вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/896244/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8

Comment: Хороплет - прям то, что надо. Вот только с определением области беда.

Comment: @ColdPol "Прикольно. Спасибо" - Извините, а что из двух? Если последнее, то есть кнопочка наверх и галочка, все слева от ответа.