# Сохранение области тепловой карты при приближении

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Есть базовые станции в виде точек. У каждой станции есть количество абонентов. Базовые станции отображаются в виде тепловых точек (температура точки зависит от количества абонентов)(модуль heatmap от Yandex). При достаточном отдолении понятно, что например город "горячий" (много абонентов), пригород "холодный" (мало абонентов). Но при приближении изображение распадается на точки. Сама по себе точка уже не особо информативна. И покрытие скажем, по районам, уже не понятно. Как сделать, чтобы при приближении город так и остался "горячим", а "пригород" холодным? 
P.S. Город и пригород  - это просто для примера. Выбираемая область может быть абсолютно любой в пределах страны. Поэтому подготовить заранее полигональные объекты (например районы) не представляется возможным.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял задачу - точка (узел) должна превратиться в полигон, чтобы его можно было масштабировать.

Как именно построить полигоны? Например, [диаграмма Вороного](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE) - для каждого узла это полигон, покрывающий такую окрестность, что этот узел является ближайшим для всех точек окрестности.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подойдёт ли это для данного случая?

Comment: Похоже, что да. Сейчас изучу вопрос.